# Getting a segmentation error in this. Tried to debug so much to no avail. where am I getting it wrong?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node{

    int data;
    Node* next;

};

Node* head;

void insert(int num){

    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp -> data = num;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    Node* temp1 = head;

    while(temp1 -> next != NULL){

        temp1 = temp1 -> next;

    }

    temp1 -> next = temp ;

}

void print(){

    Node* temp2;
    temp2 = head;

    printf("Current list is:");
    while(temp2->next != NULL){

        printf("  %d", temp2 -> data);
        temp2 = temp2 -> next;
        printf("\n");

    }

}

int main()
{
    
    head = NULL;

    insert(1);
    insert(2);
    insert(3);
    insert(4);
    insert(5);
    insert(6);
    insert(7);
    insert(8);

    print();

    return 0;
}
```

This is supposedly programmed to insert an element at end of a linked list. however compiler showing segmentation fault without any useful traceback. tried finding; but couldn't get where is this getting wrong.
also used a debugger but it isn't helping as well.

Comment: Node* head; is unitialized. You need to give it a valid value. I assume this is for a datastructures class if not use std::list. If you are know that learning about datastructures using C++ is not the same as learning C++ (as it should be used). Also try to avoid printf, use std::cout (and in C+20 use std::format for formatting strings).

Comment: Even with the correct compiler flag you will get the info you need: https://godbolt.org/z/xfonG8Kcv . On the first `insert` call, it crashes at `while(temp1 -> next != NULL)`.

Comment: Why have so much test data in `main`?  If the first insert doesn't work, then 8 of them aren't going to work.  Having less test data makes the job of debugging much easier.

Comment: By running your program line-by-line in a debugger, you should at least be able to tell in which line the segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
Node* temp1 = head;
while(temp1 -> next != NULL){
```

Consider what happens the very first time you call `insert`. The global `head` is still NULL, so `temp1` is NULL, so accessing `temp1->next` is invalid.

You need to consider the case where `head` is NULL and assign the new node there.

That's of course aside from the general bad practice here (global variable, leaking memory all over the place, no encapsulation, no destructors, using `NULL` instead of `nullptr`, C headers, ...)

Comment: note : use nullptr, not NULL

Comment: @sebastian-redl thanks! I got the point and it worked. I am just a beginner and this program especially was just a minimal test if I got the concept of linkedlist and its implementation in c++.

Answer (score 1):

In `insert()` the step `Node* temp1 = head;` you're assigning a `nullptr` to `temp1`, so therefore you cannot access its `->next` element

In this case  `head = new Node();` in `main()` would fix your issue. Ignoring practices.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never initialize `head`, meaning its value is always `NULL`. Then when you try to insert the first value into the linked list you try to access `next` on `NULL`.

Also, it looks like your `print()` function will never print the last element, because the last element's `next` is always `NULL`, therefore the condition in the `while` statement (`temp2->next != NULL`) is always `false` for the last element in the list.